# Find each field's max sequence number where unique identifier repeats

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, gaps-and-islands

I have a list of users, IDs, and activity time stamps. The data is ordered by user, ID, activity time, and a sequence number that is assigned based on all of these dimensions. I need to extract the earliest time stamp based on sequence number, then latest time stamp by sequence number for each user and ID. The problem is when the IDs repeat at a later time in the day or even the next day my code is not picking up the unique sequence of events for each ID.

So if user A performs 5 events on ID A123, then moves on the ID A567 to perform 6 events, then moves back to A123 to perform 4 additional tasks, I need the results to reflect first and last activity on ID A123, then A567, then A123 again.

Below is the current code I'm using to generate the table:

```
SELECT 
user_id,
activity_date,
foc_id,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY user_id, mno ORDER BY activity_date ) AS seq_num


FROM   cf.activity_history
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY user_id
  ORDER     BY activity_date
  MEASURES
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS mno
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (same_foc_id * last_row  )
  DEFINE
    same_foc_id AS FIRST(foc_id) = NEXT(foc_id )
)

where 
user_id in ('UVAC3','UVAH161','UVEK29','UVRB152')
and (activity_date < (sysdate - 11)
and activity_date > (sysdate - 13))

order by
user_id,
activity_date,
foc_id
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9vnH.png)

Comment: Please share the sample data in text format within the post instead of in an image.

Answer (score 0):

This reads like a gaps and island problem: an island represents a series of "adjacent" rows where a user performs the same activity, and you want the start and end of each island.

One option uses `lead()` and `lag()`. Assuming that `foc_id` identifies the activities:

```
select user_id, activity_date, foc_id
from (
    select a.*,
        lead(foc_id) over(partition by user_id order by activity_date) lead_foc_id,
        lag(foc_id) over(partition by user_id order by activity_date) lag_foc_id
    from cf.activity_history a
    where
        user_id in ('UVAC3', 'UVAH161', 'UVEK29', 'UVRB152')
        and activity_date < sysdate - 11
        and activity_date > sysdate - 13
) a
where 
    lead_foc_id is null 
    or lag_foc_id is null
    or foc_id <> lead_foc_id
    or foc_id <> lag_foc_id
```

Comment: This gets me really close... but instead of having two separate rows for the lead and lag value, I need two columns for each FOC_ID with one for lead (in time) and one for lag (out time). Additionally, I need two calculations using those times: time between in and out time and then out and next in time.

Comment: The other issue I have is when there's only one activity timestamp for a FOC_ID... At that point, the "lag" (out) time should be the same as the lead (in) time.